# Athena SQL create table with text data

Tags: amazon-athena

Below is how the data looks

```
Flight Number: SSSVAD123X Date: 2/8/2020 1:04:40 PM    Page[s] Printed: 1 Document Name: DownloadAttachment  Print Driver: printermodel (printer driver)
```

I need help creating an Athena SQL create table with in below format

```
Flight Number  Date                  Pages Printed  Document Name          Print Driver 
SSSVAD123X     2/8/2020 1:04:40 PM   1              DownloadAttachment     printermodel
```

this is new to me, any direction towards solution will work

Comment: You'll need to put that data in an S3 bucket (that Athena can read), then do a `create external table` with a Regex Serde

Comment: data is already in the S3 bucket  and it saved as below

Comment: Flight Number: SSSVAD123X Date: 2/8/2020 1:04:40 PM    Page[s] Printed: 1 Document Name: DownloadAttachment  Print Driver: printermodel (printer driver)

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to use a regex serde to parse your files. It depends on the shape of your data. You only provide a single line so this assumes that every line in your data files look the same.

Here's the Athena documentation for the feature: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/apache.html

You should be able to do something like the following:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE flights (
  flight_number STRING,
  `date` STRING,
  pages_printed INT,
  document_name STRING,
  print_driver STRING
)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.RegexSerDe'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
  "input.regex" = "^Flight Number:\\s+(\\S+)\\s+Date:\\s+(\\S+)\\s+Page\\[s\\] Printed:\\s+(\\S+)\\s+Document Name:\\s+(\\S+)\\s+Print Driver:\\s+(\\S+)\\s+\\(printer driver\\)$"
 ) LOCATION 's3://example-bucket/some/prefix/'
```

Each capture group in the regex will map to a column, in order.

Since I don't have access to your data I can't test the regex, unfortunately, so there may be errors in it. Hopefully this example is enough to get you started.

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure your data format uses tab spacing between columns because your sample doesn't seem to have a consistent separator.

```
Flight Number   Date    Pages Printed   Document Name   Print Driver 
SSSVAD123X  2/8/2020 1:04:40 PM 1   DownloadAttachment  printermodel
```

As per AWS documentation, use the LazySimpleSerDe for CSV, TSV, and Custom-Delimited Files if your data **does not include values enclosed in quotes**. You don't need to make it complicated using Regex.

Reference: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/supported-serdes.html

As LazySimpleSerDe is the default used by AWS Athena, you don't even need to declare it, see the create table statement for your data sample:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`mytable` (
    `Flight Number` STRING,
    `Date` STRING,
    `Pages Printed` INT,
    `Document Name` STRING,
    `Print Driver` STRING)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'
    ESCAPED BY '\\'
    LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
LOCATION
     's3://awsexamplebucket1-logs/AWSLogs/'
```

You can use an online generator to help you in the future: https://www.hivetablegenerator.com/

From the generator page: "Easily convert any JSON (even complex Nested ones), CSV, TSV, or Log sample file to an Apache HiveQL DDL create table statement."